# Bing Crawl Control Time Zone

Tags: bing-webmaster-tools, crawl-rate

The Crawl Control in Bing Webmaster Tools allows you to "tell Bingbot to crawl your site faster or slower than the normal crawl rate for each of the 24 hours in the day" according to http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/crawl-control-55a30302

[image: Crawl Control Bing Webmaster Tools]

This is meant to be based on "local time of day" but it seems to show MY local time of day instead of what I've set in the Geo-Targeting page. This will be accessed by team members around the world so "local" will always be somewhere different. Is there a way to tell Bing which time zone to consider as "local"?

Comment: Presumably if you set it to 9 to 5, then a person in the next time zone would see 10 to 6, no?

Comment: Andrew, Stephen is correct. The graph is always plotted against your own timezone (as in the time zone on your system). To put this to the test, you can change simply change the timezone on your system and refresh the page - you will see that the pattern will change accordingly.

Comment: @Vincent_Bing: I put your comment in as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Vincent_Bing](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/23806/vincent-bing) says:

The graph is always plotted against your own timezone (as in the time zone on your system). To put this to the test, you can change simply change the timezone on your system and refresh the page - you will see that the pattern will change accordingly.